# Unused index in range of dates query

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, order-by, query-performance

I have a query that is not using existing indices and I do not understand why.

The table:

```
mustang=# \d+ bss.amplifier_saturation
                                               Table "bss.amplifier_saturation"
 Column |           Type           |                             Modifiers                             | Storage | Description 
--------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------
 value  | integer                  | not null                                                          | plain   | 
 target | integer                  | not null                                                          | plain   | 
 start  | timestamp with time zone | not null                                                          | plain   | 
 end    | timestamp with time zone | not null                                                          | plain   | 
 id     | integer                  | not null default nextval('amplifier_saturation_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   | 
 lddate | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()                                            | plain   | 
Indexes:
    "amplifier_saturation_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "amplifier_saturation_target_start_end_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (target, start, "end")
    "amplifier_saturation_end" btree ("end")
    "amplifier_saturation_lddate" btree (lddate)
    "amplifier_saturation_start" btree (start)
    "amplifier_saturation_target" btree (target)
    "amplifier_saturation_value" btree (value)
```

The query/plan:

```
mustang=# explain select max(lddate) from bss.amplifier_saturation
where start >= '1987-12-31 00:00:00'
and   start <= '1988-04-09 00:00:00';
                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=189.41..189.42 rows=1 width=0)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..189.41 rows=1 width=8)
           ->  Index Scan Backward using amplifier_saturation_lddate on amplifier_saturation  (cost=0.00..2475815.50 rows=13071 width=8)
                 Index Cond: (lddate IS NOT NULL)
                 Filter: ((start >= '1987-12-31 00:00:00-08'::timestamp with time zone) AND (start <= '1988-04-09 00:00:00-07'::timestamp with time zone))
```

Why does this not use the index `amplifier_saturation_start`? It seems to me like the DB should scan that to find the start date, and then continue through to delimit all entries 'til the end date, and finally sort that (small subset of) data for the maximum `lddate` (something like pp40-41 of SQL Performance Explained).

I also tried an index on `(start, start desc)` in desperation but it didn't help.

Incidentally, `select count(*)` works just fine:

```
mustang=# explain select count(*) from bss.amplifier_saturation
where start >= '1987-12-31 00:00:00'
and   start <= '1988-04-09 00:00:00';
                                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                                       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=38711.84..38711.85 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Index Scan using amplifier_saturation_start on amplifier_saturation  (cost=0.00..38681.47 rows=12146 width=0)
         Index Cond: ((start >= '1987-12-31 00:00:00-08'::timestamp with time zone) AND (start <= '1988-04-09 00:00:00-07'::timestamp with time zone))
```

- Running `ANALYZE` didn't help.
- `pg_stats` shows a reasonable spread of values for start which seems to argue for using the index.
- Setting statistics to 10,000 on either column (start or `lddate`) didn't help.

Maybe I should explain why I think the plan is wrong.  The table contains **30,000,000 rows**. Only 3,500 are in the date range. But maybe that's still too many for them to be read separately?

Adding an index on `(lddate desc, start)` works (not sure the `desc` is required).  It can then use a pure index approach (IIUC) and it runs *much* faster:

```
mustang=# create index tmp_as on bss.amplifier_saturation (lddate desc, start);
CREATE INDEX
mustang=# explain select max(lddate) from bss.amplifier_saturation
where start >= '1987-12-31 00:00:00'
and   start <= '1988-04-09 00:00:00';
                                                                                       QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=69.76..69.77 rows=1 width=0)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..69.76 rows=1 width=8)
           ->  Index Scan using tmp_as on amplifier_saturation  (cost=0.00..861900.22 rows=12356 width=8)
                 Index Cond: ((lddate IS NOT NULL) AND (start >= '1987-12-31 00:00:00-08'::timestamp with time zone) AND (start <= '1988-04-09 00:00:00-07'::timestamp with time zone))
```

So, I guess to answer my own question, it seems like the cost of accessing the data 3,500 times is slower than a 30,000,000 value scan (yay spinning disks).  While a pure index scan is clearly better.

Maybe someone smarter than me comes up with a better answer?

Comment: Have you tried with an index on `(start, lddate)`?

Comment: just tried (thanks for the suggestion); it makes no difference.

Comment: This is not date range. There is daterange type in postgresql. And another type of indexes to use it. :D And querying is better for this type of problem. Check it out. ;)

Comment: i edited my title in case that was what you were objecting to.  and i can see how i could replace start/end with daterange.  but afaict this query is about a date in a range, not a daterange.

Comment: Indeed, this kind of condition is usually referred as range check (at least I use that!)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Explanation

> My question is: why does this not use the index `amplifier_saturation_start`?

Even with `30,000,000 rows, only 3,500 in the date range` it can be faster to read tuples from the top of the index `amplifier_saturation_lddate` on `lddate`. The first row that passes the filter on `start` can be returned as is. No sort step needed. With a perfectly random distribution a little below 9000 index tuples would have to be checked on average.

Using `amplifier_saturation_start`, Postgres would still have to determine`max(lddate)` after fetching all 3500 qualifying rows. Close call. The decision depends on gathered statistics and your [cost settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS). Depending on data distribution and other details one or the other will be faster, and one or the other will be *expected* to be faster.

#### Better index

This can be substantially faster with a [**multicolumn index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `(lddate, start)` like you found yourself already. This way Postgres can use an index-only scan and not touch the heap (the table) at all.

But there is another **minor** thing you can improve. Did you wonder about of this detail in your `EXPLAIN` output?

> ```
> Index Cond: ((lddate IS NOT NULL) AND ...
> ```

Why does Postgres have to exclude NULL values?
Because NULL sorts *after* the greatest value in `ASCENDING`, or *before* in `DESCENDING` order. The maximum non-null value which is returned by the aggregate function `max()` is not at the beginning / end of the index if there are NULL values. Adding [`NULLS LAST | FIRST`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492) adjusts the sort order to the characteristic of `max()` (and makes the opposite `min()` more expensive). Since we are mostly interested in the *latest* timestamp, `DESC NULLS LAST` is the better choice.

```
CREATE INDEX tmp_as ON bss.amplifier_saturation (lddate DESC NULLS LAST, start);
```

Now, your table column `lddate` obviously doesn't have NULL values, being  defined `NOT NULL`. The effect on performance will be negligible in this particular case. Still worth mentioning for cases that *can* have NULL.

The other index option would be on `(start, lddate)`, basically a pimped `amplifier_saturation_start` index, which also would allow index-only scans. Depending on data distribution and actual parameter values in your query one or the other will be faster.

#### Two notes concerning `timestamp`

1. Your table columns are `timestamptz`, but your query predicates use `timestamp` literals. Postgres derives the time zone from your current `timezone` setting and adjusts accordingly. This may or may not be as intended. It certainly makes the query *volatile* - depending on a setting of your session. It would be problematic for a call that could be made from different time zones (with differing sessions settings). Then you'd rather use an explicit offset or the `AT TIME ZONE` construct to make it *stable*. Details:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

2. You typically would want to **exclude** the upper bound for correctness. **`<`** instead of `<=`.

```
select max(lddate)
from   bss.amplifier_saturation
where  start >= '1987-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'PST'
and    start <  '1988-04-09 00:00:00 PST'::timestamptz; -- shorter
```

`PST` (pacific standard time) being a random example time zone.

Comment: awesome, thanks.  didn't know about the NULL thing (and was wondering why that constraint appeared) so will include that.  the other date things are just because i was demoing by hand (but i will double check the code is ok).  thanks again.