# Speed up Postgres Query and Function

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, functions

I have a tables that looks like this:

```
create_table "cboe_raws", force: :cascade do |t|
t.date "quote_date", null: false
t.string "underlying_symbol", null: false
t.string "security_type", null: false
t.string "option_symbol", null: false
t.date "expiration_date", null: false
t.float "strike_price", default: 0.0, null: false
t.string "call_put_flag", null: false
t.integer "days_to_expire", default: 0, null: false
t.string "series_type", null: false
t.float "first_trade_price", default: 0.0, null: false
t.float "high_trade_price", default: 0.0, null: false
t.float "low_trade_price", default: 0.0, null: false
t.float "last_trade_price", default: 0.0, null: false
t.integer "total_exchange_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "total_industry_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "open_interest", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "previous_open_interest", default: 0, null: false
t.float "previous_close", default: 0.0, null: false
t.integer "firm_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_close_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "firm_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_close_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "bd_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "mm_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "mm_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "mm_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "mm_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_close_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_lt_100_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_clsoe_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_close_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "cust_gt_199_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_close_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_lt_100_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_close_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_100_199_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_open_buy_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_open_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_close_buy_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_open_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_open_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_close_sell_qty", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "procust_gt_199_close_sell_vol", default: 0, null: false
t.boolean "active", default: true, null: false
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer "cust_100_199_close_buy_qty"
t.integer "procust_gt_199_close_buy_qty"
t.index ["active"], name: "index_cboe_raws_on_active"
t.index ["call_put_flag"], name: "index_cboe_raws_on_call_put_flag"
t.index ["expiration_date"], name: "index_cboe_raws_on_expiration_date"
t.index ["option_symbol"], name: "index_cboe_raws_on_option_symbol"
t.index ["quote_date"], name: "index_cboe_raws_on_quote_date"
t.index ["strike_price"], name: "index_cboe_raws_on_strike_price"
```

I then ran a migration to add indexes:

```
class IndexTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_index :cboe_raws, :expiration_date
    add_index :cboe_raws, :call_put_flag
    add_index :cboe_raws, :quote_date
    add_index :cboe_raws, :active
    add_index :cboe_raws, :option_symbol
    add_index :cboe_raws, :strike_price
  end
end
```

I then created a DB function as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION market_maker_books (symbol VARCHAR)
    RETURNS TABLE (
        contract_underlying_symbol VARCHAR,
        contract_expiration_date DATE,
        contract_strike_price DOUBLE PRECISION,
        contract_call_put_flag VARCHAR,
        contract_mm_buy_vol_sum BIGINT,
        contract_mm_sell_vol_sum BIGINT,
        contract_buys_minus_sells BIGINT
    )
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT underlying_symbol,
        expiration_date,
        strike_price,
        call_put_flag,
        SUM(mm_buy_vol) AS mm_buy_vol_sum,
        SUM(mm_sell_vol) AS mm_sell_vol_sum,
        SUM(mm_buy_vol) - SUM(mm_sell_vol) AS buys_minus_sells
      FROM cboe_raws
      WHERE underlying_symbol = symbol AND expiration_date >= CURRENT_DATE
      GROUP BY underlying_symbol, expiration_date, strike_price, call_put_flag
      ORDER BY expiration_date, call_put_flag, strike_price;
    END; $$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Calling the function above takes about 18-19 seconds on a databse with 8.6 million rows.
I need that to be much much faster, because this database is only going to grow.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can speed this up?

Here is the explain:

```
Function Scan on market_maker_books  (cost=0.05..3.05 rows=1000 width=164) (actual time=241.870..241.906 rows=491 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=678 read=1251
  I/O Timings: read=194.877
Planning Time: 0.029 ms
Execution Time: 241.956 ms
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions). Any particular reason you complicate things by wrapping a pretty simple query into a function?

Comment: @mustaccio I guess I just wanted it as an available function in the DB. I have another  query based off this function. Am I taking a performance hit by wrapping it in a function? I create the function in a database migration

Comment: @Jrich138: there is a performance overhead in calling a PL/pgSQL however that's only something you would notice when calling the function **many** times. But to help you we need the execution plan of the _query_ (**not** the function) using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Btw: table and index definitions are better shown as SQL statement (CREATE TABLE, CREATE INDEX). I for one am not sure what that pseudo-code is _really_ doing

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah! Got it. Thank you. I will try to use explain. I have never used it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just added the explain to the end of my question

Comment: With proper table and index definitions, your Postgres version, and the contradiction between *takes about 18-19 seconds* and `Execution Time: 241.956 ms` resolved, this would be a *useful* question.

Comment: @Jrich138: that's the explain for the function. We need the plan for the underlying query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming current Postgres 14 for lack of declaration.

#### Index

A [**multicolumn B-tree index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `(underlying_symbol, expiration_date)` would make your query fast. Any variant will do as long as `underlying_symbol` is the leading column: equality first, range later. See:

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/multicolumn-index-and-performance/33220#33220)
- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field)
- [Unused index in range of dates query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90128/unused-index-in-range-of-dates-query/90183#90183)

Even a plain index on just `(underlying_symbol)` might go a long way - depending on undisclosed data distribution.

Seeing that your table has *very* wide rows, a "covering" index might be ideal - if you get index-only scans out of it:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON cboe_raws (underlying_symbol, expiration_date DESC NULLS LAST)
INCLUDE (strike_price, call_put_flag, mm_buy_vol, mm_sell_vol, mm_buy_vol);
```

#### Function

You typically don't need PL/pgSQL for a single, plain SQL query. Use an SQL function instead. I suggest the new standard-SQL variant:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION market_maker_books(_symbol varchar)
  RETURNS TABLE (contract_underlying_symbol varchar
               , contract_expiration_date date
               , contract_strike_price float8
               , contract_call_put_flag varchar
               , contract_mm_buy_vol_sum bigint
               , contract_mm_sell_vol_sum bigint
               , contract_buys_minus_sells bigint)
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT c.underlying_symbol
     , c.expiration_date
     , c.strike_price
     , c.call_put_flag
     , SUM(c.mm_buy_vol)  -- AS mm_buy_vol_sum
     , SUM(c.mm_sell_vol) -- AS mm_sell_vol_sum
     , SUM(c.mm_buy_vol) - SUM(c.mm_sell_vol) -- AS buys_minus_sells
FROM   cboe_raws c
WHERE  c.underlying_symbol = _symbol
AND    c.expiration_date >= CURRENT_DATE
GROUP  BY c.underlying_symbol, c.expiration_date, c.strike_price, c.call_put_flag
ORDER  BY c.expiration_date, c.call_put_flag, c.strike_price;
END;
```

See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC ... END mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300507/what-does-begin-atomic-end-mean-in-a-postgresql-sql-function-procedure/300512#300512)

Might be untangled and compacted further:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION market_maker_books(_symbol varchar)
  RETURNS TABLE (expiration_date date
               , call_put_flag varchar
               , strike_price float8
               , mm_buy_vol_sum bigint
               , mm_sell_vol_sum bigint
               , buys_minus_sells bigint)
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT c.expiration_date, c.call_put_flag, c.strike_price
     , SUM(c.mm_buy_vol)
     , SUM(c.mm_sell_vol)
     , SUM(c.mm_buy_vol) - SUM(c.mm_sell_vol)
FROM   cboe_raws c
WHERE  c.underlying_symbol = _symbol
AND    c.expiration_date >= CURRENT_DATE
GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER  BY 1, 2, 3;
END;
```