# What's the fastest way to find the first 2 purchases for every customer in Redshift?

Tags: redshift

I'm looking to find the first 2 purchases for every customer.

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
orders
```

With columns:

```
order_id
customer_email
grand_total
purchase_date
```

There are many millions of rows in this table and I'm trying to look for an efficient way to grab the first two earliest records for each customer, so that I get a result set that looks something like this:

```
order_id
customer_email
purchase_date1
purchase_date2
```

I'm at a loss on how to do this efficiently.

Comment: `order_id` can't be in your result set... either it's `customer_email, order_id1, order_id2` or `customer_email, purchase_date1, purchase_date2`.

Comment: @Colin'tHart - to be more specific, data that's consistent for all rows for a customer, or that ultimately comes from a customer table, can be shown once for the top two orders; information that can be different from one order to another should be shown explicitly for the two orders. `order_id` will be different for the first two orders, so you (logically) should show the order_id for each order. Now, `purchase_date` could actually be the same for the top two orders, but it could be different, so you should show both purchase dates as well. ...

Comment: ... For that matter, we're assuming that `customer_email` uniquely identifies a specific customer; perhaps a customer may specify a different email for two orders, but still be recognized as the same customer. **TL;DR**: `customer_email`,`order_id1`,`purchase_date`,`order_id2`,`purchase_date2` might well be valid, as well - you aren't limited to just one field from the unique elements of `order`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a separate `customers` table, and a compound index on `orders(customer_email, purchase_date)`, something like this will do it:

```
select
  customer_email,
  array(
    select order_id
    from orders
    where customer_email = c.customer_email
    order by purchase_date
    limit 2
  ) as order_ids
from customers c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a window function might be an option:

```
select * from (
  select customer_email, purchase_date, order_id, 
         row_number() over (partition by customer_email order by purchase_date) rn
  from orders
) t where rn < 3
```

Comment: Is Postgres smart enough not to calculate row_numbers for all orders, and to use an index to do so? At least with correlated subquery with limit, I have gotten it to only "walk the index" for the first rows for each customer. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51895/efficient-query-to-get-greatest-value-per-group-from-big-table