# Joining only one row of a table?

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this query which is supposed to find the latest uploaded pids and reps of a user. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT usr.id, up.*, 
      (SELECT COALESCE(state, 'processing') AS pidState FROM PID WHERE userId = usr.id ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 1),
      (SELECT COALESCE(state, 'processing') AS repState FROM REP WHERE userId = usr.id ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 1),
      (SELECT createdAt AS pidCreatedAt FROM PID WHERE userId = usr.id ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 1),
      (SELECT createdAt AS repCreatedAt FROM REP WHERE userId = usr.id ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM User AS usr
JOIN UserProfile AS up ON up.userId = usr.id
ORDER BY pidCreatedAt DESC NULLS LAST, repCreatedAt DESC NULLS LAST
```

I tried joining PID and REP to the User but that gave me a load of returned rows since I only want the latest from each. Now I also have the need to return the PID and REP `id` fields, which would result in another subquery, so I am wondering if there's a smarter way to solve this other than to keep on writing sub queries for every column that I need in the future?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: `APPLY` or `LATERAL` would probably help here, but see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group

Comment: `user` is a reserved word, which would raise an exception when used as table name like this. Please provide your actual query, and be clear whether it produces desired results. Also your version of Postgres and table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements).

Answer (score 2):

Based on a couple of assumptions, this might be the query you are looking for:

```
SELECT up.*
     , p.pidState, p.pidCreatedAt  -- more?
     , r.repState, r.repCreatedAt  -- more?
FROM   UserProfile AS up
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (userId)
          userId
        , COALESCE(state, 'processing') AS pidState
        , createdAt AS pidCreatedAt
        -- , more columns from PID
   FROM   PID
   ORDER  BY userId, createdAt DESC NULLS LAST
   ) p USING (userId)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (userId)
          userId
        , COALESCE(state, 'processing') AS repState
        , createdAt AS repCreatedAt
        -- , more columns from REP
   FROM  REP
   ORDER BY userId, createdAt DESC NULLS LAST
   ) r USING (userId)
ORDER  BY pidCreatedAt DESC NULLS LAST, repCreatedAt DESC NULLS LAST
```

If referential integrity is guaranteed by a FK constraint, you can just omit the table `User` (invalid name) from the query.

While fetching all or most rows it typically makes sense to run subqueries with `DISTINCT ON` (or a related technique) on the whole tables `PID` and `REP`.

For a small selection, `LATERAL` subqueries will be more efficient.

See these related answers for detailed explanations:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)
- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)
- [Efficient query to get greatest value per group from big table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51895/efficient-query-to-get-greatest-value-per-group-from-big-table/52015#52015)

Aside: use legal, lowercase, unquoted identifiers in Postgres if possible. Makes your life easier.

Comment: I could be more specific if the question was more specific.